# Flutter app throwing multiple errors when tried to run in virtual device(API 33)

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

I'm new to flutter and trying to run a template app on the emulator, however when I click run, the console output log shows multiple error. Output log Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'.

Output log:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth-3.4.0/lib/src/firebase_auth.dart:589:23: Error: The method 'signInWithAuthProvider' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAuthPlatform'.
 - 'FirebaseAuthPlatform' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_firebase_auth.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.10.0/lib/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_firebase_auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'signInWithAuthProvider'.
      await _delegate.signInWithAuthProvider(provider),
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth-3.4.0/lib/src/recaptcha_verifier.dart:57:27: Error: Required named parameter 'auth' must be provided.
      _factory.delegateFor(
                          ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter_windows_3.7.8-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter_windows_3.7.8-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I'm not sure what these errors mean or how to fix them. Can someone please help me troubleshoot this issue and provide guidance on how to get my app running on my Android device?

**These are the versions I'm using:**

Flutter 3.7.8
• channel stable
• https://github.com/flutter/flutter.gitFramework
• revision 90c64ed42b (8 days ago)
• 2023-03-21 11:27:08 -0500Engine
• revision 9aa7816315Tools
• Dart 2.19.5
• DevTools 2.20.1

Comment: Try upgrading firebase_auth package  version. Current version on pub.dev is firebase_auth: ^4.3.0.

Comment: No it doesnt work it throws another error
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter-login-screen-firebase-auth-facebook-login-master...
Resolving dependencies... 
Because firebase_auth >=4.3.0 depends on firebase_core ^2.8.0 and flutter_login_screen depends on firebase_core ^1.8.0, firebase_auth >=4.3.0 is forbidden.
So, because flutter_login_screen depends on firebase_auth ^4.3.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\flutter_windows_3.7.8-stable\flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\sunny\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",
}

Comment: Do overall package upgrade. flutter pub upgrade

Comment: Resolving dependencies...
Because firebase_auth >=4.3.0 depends on firebase_core ^2.8.0 and flutter_login_screen depends on firebase_core ^1.8.0, firebase_auth >=4.3.0 is forbidden.
So, because flutter_login_screen depends on firebase_auth ^4.3.0, version solving failed.

this is the error im getting,  all are dependent on the older version